# thymeaf layout usage not functional

Tags: thymeleaf

Hi I want to use a custom fragment in thymeleaf
I have a layout file which is not loaded by other hmtl files, main.html:
I want to use a custom fragment in thymeleaf

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>SFJ - Egy sztori minden napra</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/blog.css" th:href="@{/css/blog.css}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
             
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="/">Kezdőoldal</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="/stories">Sztorik</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="/bloggers">Bloggerek</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                        Üdvözlünk <span sec:authentication="name">Anonymous </span>
                           <form sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" id="frmlogout" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" class="form-inline">
                                | <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('frmlogout').submit(); return false;">Kijelentkezés</a>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <div layout:fragment="loginContent">
            </div>
    
    
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>      
            <footer>
                <p>San Franciscoból Jöttem - Az eredeti template összeállítója: http://therealdanvega.com</p>
            </footer>
        
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I try to load it for example from login.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" layout:decorator="layouts/main">
    <head>
    <title>SFJ - Minden napra egy sztori</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div layout:fragment="loginContent">
    
            <form name="login" th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="form-signin">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">KÃ©rlek jelentkezz be</h2>
                <div id="err" th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">HibÃ¡s felhasznÃ¡lÃ³i nÃ©v Ã©s jelszÃ³</div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">Sikeresen kijelentkeztÃ©l</div>
                <label for="username" class="sr-only">FelhasznÃ¡lÃ³i nÃ©v</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="FelhasznÃ¡lÃ³i nÃ©v" required="true" /> 
                <label for="password" class="sr-only">JelszÃ³</label> 
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="JelszÃ³" required="true" />
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label> <input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox" /> EmlÃ©kezz rÃ¡m
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">BejelentkezÃ©s</button>
            </form>
    
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

It doesn't not find the main.html, does not take into account...
It's loading only the content from login.html
Does anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: You are using the fragments in the wrong way... Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#flexible-layouts-beyond-mere-fragment-insertion) and this [extended example](https://o7planning.org/12369/thymeleaf-page-layout).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think, I didn't ask the right question. In fact I have problem, with the decorator, the fragment created in the login.html is working. The decorator is not working which was created in layouts/main.html. I referred to it from login.html like this layout:decorator="layouts/main"

Comment: Did you add the `nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect` dependency in your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Thank you. It's working now with the following dependency: <dependency>
   <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.3</version>
  </dependency>